# Return value of JPA query when no matches found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, named-query

I'm using `Spring JPA named querys` in my repository. My problem is, that I can't find anywhere information what would be returned value for a query that wouldn't match any results. I assume it'll be null for `findOne()` but I have no idea what would it be for `findAllByName()` function.

Does anyone know from his/her experience or know a place in documentation?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From my little and personal experience, if you search for an object on your repo, for example, by Id or Name the named query method returns an object of type `T`, but if no results are found from your repo, it will return `null`.

Methods that can return more than one element, will produce an empty collection `List<T>`(not null).

Some documentation here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords

> Appendix D: Repository query return types

> Supported query return types
> Query return types:

> T An unique entity. Expects the query method to
> return one result at most. In case no result is found null is
> returned. More than one result will trigger an
> IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException.

> Iterator An Iterator.

It seems only when the return type is of type `T` is the only one that specifies a `null` is returned if there are no matches.

Comment: damn NP hehe! how many if != null statements will be avoided by better reading / better documentation.

Comment: A repository with @RepositoryRestResource incase of an empty list, will return a list with one "dummyObject" ..how could i make it return just an empty list? It returns this:"content": [
    {
      "value": [],
      "rel": null,
      "collectionValue": true,
      "relTargetType": "com.xy.xy.xy.model.Campaign"
    }
  ]-------------------but i need just content[]